# NDK issue on Android Studio: "process ... command finished with non-zero exit value 2"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

### Background

I'm trying to import an old Eclipse JNI project ([**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations)), and yet even after all my attempts, I always fail.

The project worked fine on Eclipse (well most of the times) and somehow many users have succeeded importing it and using it on Android-Studio. All except the creator - me.

I've put the instructions someone told me and also merged all changes that are related to this issue, but nothing still works for me.

### What I've tried

I've tried to follow those steps:

1. Create a 'jni' folder under src/main/ folder and copy JniBitmapOprationsLibrary.cpp to this folder.
2. Add a package com.jni.bitmap_operations, and add JniBitmapHolder.java to this package.
3. Add your NDK path to local.properties
4. Import com.jni.bitmap_operations package where it will be used
   And it should be fine, except the NewDirectBuffer issue on my side.
5. put the fake 0-sized "c" file into the 'jni' folder.

I've tried other special steps I've found too, but nothing works. This is the current error I'm getting:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':jnibitmapoperationslibrary:compileDebugNdk'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'D:\android\ndk\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

### The question

How do I really suppose to import or create JNI projects on Android Studio? Will the projects be able to compile and be debugged?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, the JNI should not be in src/main. It should be in top of project folder.

I think it's all. I know there is also issues with gradle when trying to build native projects. Not sure they fixed it yet.

Also, take a look at other ndk tools, like "android update project -p ." which generates files needed to build (with ndk-build)

Comment: Actually, the one I currently have on Github has the "jni" folder on the top project folder (the one of the library module). It agreed to launch, but crashed on runtime, saying "couldn't find "libJniBitmapOperationsLibrary.so"" .  Also tried to put it into "src"

Comment: Ok I see. If I recall well, bitmap stuff from jni or ndk need to be built with ndk-build too.
If you take a look at the Android.mk in jni folder, there should be something like LOCAL_LDLIBS += "something related to libbitmap".
Definitely not sure that it's your exact lib, but it's worth looking for.

Comment: you mean LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -ljnigraphics , but it's already there, as it always worked via Eclipse (except for when it had weird issues).

Comment: Did you manage to make it work ? I'm getting the same "couldn't find "libJniBitmapOperationsLibrary.so"" error on a project imported from eclipse which uses your library.

Comment: I don't know if OP is still here, but after a while working with NDK and Android Studio, the best solution I could find in my projects to build C++ code was manually calling the tools like ndk-build from command-line :/
Gradle is definitely not operational for building with NDK at the moment